# Apache CXF Spring Java Config for JAXWS Endpoint

Tags: spring, cxf

I'm trying to configure Spring with Apache CXF using java config (no XML config) and wanted to know how to register JAXWS endpoints using spring java config. For example, what would be the 'java config' equivalent for the XML config below?

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="reportService" implementor="#reportServ" address="/reportService"/>
```

Kind regards,
Zahanghir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'Java-config' equivalent of your XML configuration is something like :

```
@Configuration
public class CXFConfiguration {

   @Autowired
   private ReportService reportServ;

   @Bean
   public Endpoint endpoint() {
       Endpoint endpoint = new EndpointImpl(reportServ);
       endpoint.publish("/reportService");
       return endpoint;
   }

}
```

I hope this can help you ^^.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, from what I can tell KevinHol's answer doesn't actually work. A working answer can be found at the sister thread ([Apache CXF + Spring Java config (no XML)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223626/apache-cxf-spring-java-config-no-xml)).