# Getting JAX-WS WebServices working in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, jax-ws

I have some legacy JAX-WS @WebService annotated classes. I am trying to get this working in spring-boot. Been looking at https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/spring/ as a reference as well as http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html.

My @SpringBootAnnotated class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class SpringBootBooter extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean servletRegistrationBean() {
        ServletRegistrationBean reg = new ServletRegistrationBean(new WSSpringServlet(),"/myws");
        reg.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        return reg;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(new Object[] {
            SpringBootBooter.class,
            new ClassPathResource("myLegacyAppContextWithWSBean.xml")
        }, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        super.onStartup(servletContext);
        servletContext.addListener(new WSServletContextListener());
    }
}
```

My XML config for the WS implementation class

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
  xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
  xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
    http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet
    http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">

  <wss:binding url="/myws">
    <wss:service>
      <ws:service bean="#mywsbean" />
    </wss:service>
  </wss:binding>

  <bean id="mywsbean" class="com.items.MyWsBean">
  </bean>

</beans>
```

When everything boots up, I go to localhost:8080/myws and just get back "404 Not Found: Invalid Request".

Just not sure what I am missing, its like something is not parsing those wss:binding XML declarations to tie together these servlet requests to the bean, and I am not sure how to do this in spring-boot.

This appears in logs when I first hit that mapped URI

```
Jul 15, 2015 9:40:18 AM com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate <init>
INFO: WSSERVLET14: JAX-WS servlet initializing
```

thanks

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: I abandoned what I was trying to do above, and just registered a CXF servlet following this example link below. I simply could not get any of the spring documented things to work (in particular the above): https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/3104

Comment: In short however, this particular issue I describe above is still not solved

Comment: Starting from Spring 4.x, the XML configuration is not recommended any more - I advice the usage of Spring´s Java Configuration. I described how to set up SpringBoot and Apache CXF in another answer already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21223626/apache-cxf-spring-java-config-no-xml/36137189#36137189

Comment: Not sure what exactly is the problem, but I got it running with only little modification (I had to update the locations for jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core and jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet). Maybe there was a dependency conflict, with the JAX-WS and Spring stuff, hard to tell without the pom. Anyhow, I wrote a [tutorial on how to integrate Spring Boot and JAX-WS RI](http://herrho.com/jax-ws-webservice-with-spring-boot-and-jax-ws-ri/)

Answer (score -4):

Your solution appears rather complex. You can get a JAX-WS service running with Spring Boot, using only

These Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web"
  compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey"
}
```

This configuration class (Groovy):

```
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component

@Component
class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    JerseyConfig() {
        register(MyResource)
    }
}
```

This resource class:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import javax.ws.rs.GET
import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.Produces
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType

@Component
@Path("/foo")
class MyResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Map bar() {
      return ["hello":"world"]
    }
}
```

and this:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoJaxWSService {

  static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run DemoJaxWSService, args
  }
}
```

Your endpoint will be available at `localhost:8080/foo`

Comment: I am trying to take legacy JAX-WS (soap) annotated classes and run them in spring boot. Your example is showing a REST service.

Comment: Oh, sorry! My mistake